# How to correctly set AUTO INCREMENT fo a column in SQLite, using Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

I have been trying with the below code:

```
import sqlite3
data_person_name = [('Michael', 'Fox'),
                    ('Adam', 'Miller'),
                    ('Andrew', 'Peck'),
                    ('James', 'Shroyer'),
                    ('Eric', 'Burger')]
con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
c = con.cursor()
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE q1_person_name
             (name_id integer auto_increment primary key,
              first_name varchar(20) NOT NULL,
              last_name varchar(20) NOT NULL)''')
c.executemany('INSERT INTO q1_person_name VALUES (?,?,?)', data_person_name)
for row in c.execute('SELECT * FROM q1_person_name'):
    print row
```

Can somebody help me in making the `name_id` automatically incremented ?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

In SQLite, `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` column is auto-incremented. There is also an `AUTOINCREMENT` keyword. When used in `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`, a
slightly different algorithm for Id creation is used.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sqlite3
data_person_name = [('Michael', 'Fox'),
                    ('Adam', 'Miller'),
                    ('Andrew', 'Peck'),
                    ('James', 'Shroyer'),
                    ('Eric', 'Burger')]

con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")

with con:

    c = con.cursor()

    c.execute('''CREATE TABLE q1_person_name
                 (name_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                  first_name varchar(20) NOT NULL,
                  last_name varchar(20) NOT NULL)''')
    c.executemany('INSERT INTO q1_person_name(first_name, last_name) VALUES (?,?)', data_person_name)

    for row in c.execute('SELECT * FROM q1_person_name'):
        print(row)
```

This code now works OK.

```
c.executemany('INSERT INTO q1_person_name(first_name, last_name) VALUES (?,?)', data_person_name)
```

When using auto-increment, we have to explicitly state the column names, omitting the
one that is auto-incremented.

```
$ ./test.py 
(1, u'Michael', u'Fox')
(2, u'Adam', u'Miller')
(3, u'Andrew', u'Peck')
(4, u'James', u'Shroyer')
(5, u'Eric', u'Burger')
```

This is the output of the code example.

Answer (score 3):

Replace the first `?` in `executemany` statement with `null`.

So the following line can be rewritten:

```
c.executemany('INSERT INTO q1_person_name VALUES (?,?,?)', data_person_name)
```

as

```
c.executemany('INSERT INTO q1_person_name VALUES (null,?,?)', data_person_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you've done it already. So there's no need to reference that field when you insert.

```
INSERT INTO q1_person_name (first_name, last_name) VALUES (?,?)
```

Comment: When i do this it asssigns the `name_id` to **None**

Answer (score -1):

Try like this:

```
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE q1_person_name
         (name_id integer primary key AUTOINCREMENT,
          first_name varchar(20) NOT NULL,
          last_name varchar(20) NOT NULL)''')
```